# My Enemy wont draw

Tags: java, eclipse, rendering, lwjgl

I am making a -very- simple 1v1 game and my Enemy won't draw. This is the Code for my Game:

The Main Class:

```
package Generic;

import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;

public class Main {

    public static Player player;
    public static Enemy enemy;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode (640, 480));
Display.create();

player = new Player();
//Game
while(!Display.isCloseRequested()) 
     {

    setCamera();
    drawBackground();
    player.draw();
    enemy.draw();
    Display.sync(60);
    Display.update();

    }

Display.destroy(); 


    }

    public static void setCamera(){
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    //Clear Screen
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    //Projection Matrix
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, 640, 0, 480, -1, 1);

    //Modify ModelView Matrix
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    }

    public static void drawBackground() {

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);  
    //Draw Sky
    glColor3d(0.7, 0.8, 0.9);
    glVertex2d(0, 0);
    glVertex2d(640, 0);

    glColor3d(0.5, 0.6, 0.9);
    glVertex2d(640, 480);
    glVertex2d(0, 480);

    glEnd();

    //Draw Ground

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);

    glColor3d(0.5, 0.25, 0.1);
    glVertex2d(0, 0);
    glVertex2d(640, 0);

    glVertex2d(640, 32);
    glVertex2d(0, 32);

    glEnd();

    //Draw Grass

glBegin(GL_QUADS);

    glColor3d(0, 0.7, 0.1);
    glVertex2d(0, 25);
    glVertex2d(640, 25);

    glVertex2d(640, 32);
    glVertex2d(0, 32);

    glEnd();
    }

}
```

The Player Class:

```
package Generic;


import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;

public class Player {

    public double x, y, xspeed, yspeed;
    public Player() {
        x=100;
        y=100;

    }

public void draw() {


      glPushMatrix();


      glTranslated(x, y, 0);

      glBegin(GL_QUADS);

      glColor3d(1, 0, 0);
      glVertex2d(-8, 0);

      glColor3d(0, 1, 0);
      glVertex2d(8, 0);

      glColor3d(0, 0, 1);
      glVertex2d(8, 16);

      glColor3d(1, 1, 0);
      glVertex2d(-8, 16);

      glEnd();

      glPopMatrix();


}
    }
```

The Enemy Class:

```
package Generic;


import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;


public class Enemy {

    public double x, y;
    public Enemy() {
        x=200;
        y=32;

    }

public void logic()
{
    x+=1;
    if(x<=640+10) x = -10;

}

public void draw() {

    logic();  

      glPushMatrix();

      glTranslated(x, y, 0);

      glBegin(GL_QUADS);

      glColor3d(1, 0, 0);
      glVertex2d(-8, 0);

      glColor3d(0, 1, 0);
      glVertex2d(8, 0);

      glColor3d(0, 0, 1);
      glVertex2d(8, 16);

      glColor3d(1, 1, 0);
      glVertex2d(-8, 16);

      glEnd();

      glPopMatrix();


}
    }
```

The Enemy (Which should be a cube) is not being drawn on the screen. Please help as I am new to Java/LWJGL and don't know how to solve it on my own

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are calling `drawBackground` after drawing the enemy, which is most likely covering your enemy?

Remember that when drawing things to the screen, the computer is going to draw them in the order you call them regardless of it being the background or some kind of object.

Comment: @tansihalfeleven Oops, I changed that and it didn't work still. Any ideas?

Comment: @Epicpwnage2010 Also you should `Display.update()` before `Display.sync(60)`

Comment: It still won't draw... Any other sugestions?

Comment: @Epicpwnage2010 Well, what is happening? Is the player rendering? Is the background rendering?

Comment: @tanishalfeleven The Player and Background are rendering, but the enemy is not.

Comment: @Epicpwnage2010 In your `Enemy.logic()` method, you are setting the `x = -10`, which is most likely out of bounds of the screen. Your check, `if(x<=640+10)` will always be true because you increment `x` every frame, and `x = 200` at the beginning. Does that fix it?